# on flag click get series (graph) it's on highstock?

Tags: highcharts

I have several flags series, each of these series belongs to different graphs (i use onSeries prop). I want to know on which graph the flag is on when i click on it, so that when i use the click event in plotOptions.series.point.events.click i could get the graph point and not the flag point.

```
plotOptions.series.point.events.click = function(){console.log(this)}
```

i have tried to pass the event param in to the callback but there is nothing conserning the graph it's on

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the *this.options* array. The onSeries option is available with *this.options.onSeries*.

Here is a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/yP5z3/1/